# Android NEON libraries

Tags: android, arm, libraries, neon

Is there any other free vector library optimized for neon that math-neon?
I would like to get advantage of neon in my code, i have lot of objects and i am doing lot of simple vector physics-math, like adding vectors, multiplying, dotting them, those are 3d vectors but if i could make it a lot faster 2d should be ok too, the question is, is it worth using neon? for example lets take 100000 points, i need to calculate their movement, collisions etc. I am currently using my own math, and its based on inline functions, lets say that i would like to use my hypothetical neon library with matrices too, currently i am using glm for that, and its doing fine, but could it be faster? Speed advantage between arm-abi and arm7-abi in ndk is about 30 percent in my case, can neon be faster or maybe my code is translated to neon in compile time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check [eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page). It has special code that it is activated when neon instruction support is activated.

Answer (score 0):

Like someone else mentioned, you should look into Eigen, it is probably good enough for you. But if you want full performance (much better than 30% gain, more like 300% gain), you should use NEON code yourself and make sure your entire inner loop is written completely with NEON (not any CPU or VFP code).

If you just NEON optimize part of your loop instead of the entire loop, you get major penalties and so the NEON code is perhaps just 30% faster or perhaps even slower than regular C code. But a full NEON loop can often give you 300% - 2000% speedup!

If you are developing for an ARM Cortex-A9 then NEON C Intrinsics should be good enough, but for ARM Cortex-A8 devices you usually need NEON Assembly code to get full performance. I give some more info on how to NEON optimize your whole loop at "http://www.shervinemami.info/armAssembly.html"

Answer (score -3):

Code is compiled for NEON if the target architecture supports it, namely, if it is compiled for armeabi-v7a. To do this, simply add `armeabi-v7a` to the list of targets in your app's Application.mk file.

Comment: I have already did it and it gives 30percent speed up , but is armeabi-v7a for vfp, neon or both, do neon require asm code and special instructions or they are translated in compile time?, math-neon consists of asm code so i think that to use neon capabilities i need to have asm code, maybe simple operations are translated in compile time and others need asm code?

Comment: The NDK page (http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html) doesn't mention any assembly code, so it would appear that all compatible code is optimized for NEON and VFP automatically when compiled for v7a. The NDK docs also give an example on how to load the correct library for the architecture it is being executed, i.e. ARM5 or ARM7 (see link). For more information on their NDK and Android support, check out the CPU-ARCH-ABIS and CPU-ARM-NEON help html files in the NDK/docs folder.

Comment: The neon intrinsic code is indeed fast enough. But for some codes like vld2,vld3 etc it seems to be compiled badly. Looking in the assembly one can find that mostly the loaded values gets pushed to stack. In such cases the asm coding is appropriate.

Comment: Don't expect your code to automatically be optimized using NEON just because you use armeabi-v7a. To use NEON, you should explicitly use NEON in your code (or use a NEON library such as Eigen).